# Linking with gcc on Windows:

Tags: c, windows, gcc, dll, mingw

I'm trying to link a c-file (`cvode.c`) towards a set of .dll files.  I run the following two lines in a cmd:

```
>>> gcc -c -I C:\sundials\inst2\include cvode.c

>>> gcc -shared -o cvode_lib.dll cvode.o -L. C:\sundials\inst2\lib\sundials_cvode.dll -L. C:\sundials\inst2\lib\sundials_nvecserial.dll
```

The first command does not give any errors but the second one gives the following error message:

```
C:\sundials\inst2\lib\sundials_cvode.dll: file not recognized: File format not recognized
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

If I try to import the dll-files with ipython it works perfect, and the same two lines (with the same source files) works perfectly on my second computer running the same OS (windows 10 64bit) with the same version of gcc (installed with the latest Mingw64-installer).  I've also tried to install cygwin64 and compile with its gcc-version, without success.  The file compiles perfectly fine on an Ubuntu computer as well.

I have also tried to link vs the corresponding `<sundials>`.lib-files but that is not working either.

Googling for solutions has not been successful, maybe because I am not too familiar with c or gcc.  However since it runs perfect on my other Win10 PC I fear it might be something deeper...

Comment: Thank you for your comment.  They are indeed built with VS ( I did that myself with CMAKE, VS and msbuild).  However as far as I know I did it in exactly the same way on my other computer (i.e. building the source with CMAKE and VS) and it works there.  I didn't manage to get CMAKe to work with gcc, which is why I used VS.  For the file Im trying to compile above I'd like to use gcc since the compile command is easy to transfer between Win and Linux.  Maybe the easiest way is to ditch Windows and move to Linux :p

Comment: Sorry I didn't read your question right, my previous comment doesn't even make sense. I removed it.